# c++ program performance difference in docker 3X slower

Tags: c++, docker

I have c++ program and processing 1M lines , find pattern and select part of it as an example below .

The strange thing is its running almost 3 times slower in the docker in the same machine ?

both host / guest ubuntu 20.04 and same g++-8 compiled.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin =
          std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      for (int i = 1; i <= val; ++i) {
        

        auto cx = data[i].find("sub");
        auto type_ = data[i].find("type"); //!= std::string::npos)
        type_ = data[i].find("type");

        type_ = data[i].find("applist");
    
        string str3 = data[1].substr(45, 110);

        str3 = data[1].substr(45, 110);
        str3 = data[1].substr(45, 110);
        str3 = data[1].substr(45, 110);
       
        
      }
```

Comment: this is completly normal, docker uses virtualization and is not exactly what we could call optimized for performances. You won't have the same performances on your machine than when using docker

Comment: Your code has no side effects, so I wouldn't be surprised if it all got optimized out.

Comment: Are you including the overhead of starting the container, or attaching to a running container and then profiling your program inside it?

Comment: What exactly are you timing?  Does it include file I/O? (That often takes a big hit in a VM).

Comment: @R.LM Your statement is untrue. If the host is Linux, there is no virtualization involved by default. The container is just a process running in a different process/network namespace.

Comment: Hi after stated docker benchmark is starting. And no IO or file read is included benchmark . Pure vector and string::find  and string::substr.

Comment: @AILORD what could be this slowness problem almost 3x?